# restricting access page feedback in dspace?

Tags: java, xslt, dspace

I am using the 5.5 version of DSpace

and interface XMLUI

Guys sorry for the noob question, as we all know, attacks and spam in the IT world are common,it's possible you can restrict the access page "/ feedback" from dspace only to authenticated users. DSpace itself has some kind of protection against attacks that can bring down the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To restrict the /feedback page to authenticated users, you need to edit `/aspects/ArtifactBrowser/sitemap.xmap`. Add the `AuthenticatedSelector` to the "feedback" matcher:

```
<map:match pattern="feedback">
    <map:select type="AuthenticatedSelector">
        <map:when test="eperson">
            <map:act type="SendFeedbackAction">
                <map:transform type="FeedbackForm">
                    <map:parameter name="comments" value="{comments}"/>
                    <map:parameter name="email" value="{email}"/>
                    <map:parameter name="page" value="{page}"/>
                </map:transform>
                <map:serialize type="xml"/>
            </map:act>
            <map:transform type="FeedbackSent"/>
        </map:when>
        <map:otherwise>
            <map:act type="StartAuthentication"/>
        </map:otherwise>
    </map:select>
    <map:serialize type="xml"/>
</map:match>
```

This `otherwise` block will redirect users that aren't authenticated in to the log in page.